# How to find and update spesific element inside a <li> list

Tags: jquery

I have a entry in my list that looks like the html code provided.
When the edit button is clicked i want to change the checkbox value to another value.

This is just one out of many entreies on my list, so the code i come up with is also provided under the html code.

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label class="form-checkbox form-normal form-primary active">
        <input class="category" name="category" type="checkbox"> Vale to be changed
    </label>
    <a href="#" data-id="1" data-name="A value" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" data-id="1" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs del">Delete</a>
</div>
```

Jquery simplefied example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    response = true;

    if(response){
        $('.edit').prev('label').find('.category').text('new value');
    }
});
```

Comment: ...what `<li>` list?

Comment: where is the <edit> selector?

Comment: This is largely typos. You want `$(".edit")`, not `$("edit")`, and you want `.find(".category")`, not `.find(".castegory")`. Please at least ensure you've resolved basic problems like that before posting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you may be right - but I read the question as though the OP is trying to change the text within the sibling textNode of the checkbox.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: I see what you mean.

Comment: Thanks to @Rory McCrossan!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have here is that the text you're trying to target is in a textNode so you need to use `content()` and `filter()` to find and then amend it, like this:

```js
$('.btn.edit').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('label').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.trim();
  })[0].nodeValue = 'new value';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="form-checkbox form-normal form-primary active">
    <input class="category" name="category" type="checkbox">Vale to be changed
  </label>
  <a href="#" data-id="1" data-name="A value" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit">Edit</a>
  <a href="#" data-id="1" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs del">Delete</a>
</div>
```

This process can be made *much* simpler if you wrap that textNode in its own element, such as a `span`:

```js
$('.btn.edit').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.checkbox').find('label span').text('new value');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
  <label class="form-checkbox form-normal form-primary active">
    <input class="category" name="category" type="checkbox"> <span>Vale to be changed</span>
  </label>
  <a href="#" data-id="1" data-name="A value" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs edit">Edit</a>
  <a href="#" data-id="1" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs del">Delete</a>
</div>
```